# data normalization range and scale

Tags: excel, normalization, normal-distribution

I want to normalize this data 2,100,-50,75,10000,300000,-50000,
how to fix normalization range with same scale.
i am using z score normalization in excel but normalization value is not in the same scale . how to get normalize data in a same scale

Comment: Show your input & output. Normalization is term of database. So make clear what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you are looking for is `STANDARDIZE` but you may need to get the mean and the standard deviation of the set first:

[image]

in this example I have calculate the mean (`AVERAGE`) in D2 and then standard deviation (`STDEV`) in E2 and finally applied `STANDARDIZE` to the data in A in column B